# How to properly embed Bootstrap collapse.js?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I import collapse.js for Bootstrap 5.3

Collapse work with this line but i have an Error

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/collapse.js"></script>
```

Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at collapse.js:8:1)

When I write it like this the error message is gone but collapse does not work anymore.
It collapses off but no longer on. what is wrong?

```
<script type="module" src="assets/js/collapse.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add HTML/CSS/JS. We need to be able to reproduce the problem.